# Asp.net Blazor System.DllNotFoundException: e_sqlite3

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, asp.net-core, blazor

[SteveSandersonMSBlazeOrbital](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazeOrbital/)

i am trying to launch the Steve's Sanderson Blazer Orbital project.
i added SQLitePCLRaw.Bundle_e_sqlite3 package via NuGet manager.
but project throws an exception :

```
System.DllNotFoundException: e_sqlite3
at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3.SQLitePCL.ISQLite3Provider.sqlite3_libversion_number()
at SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider(ISQLite3Provider imp)
```

any suggestion , how to solve the problem ?

Comment: Could you show more details about how to reproduce the issue, I have tried to add the package in all the projects, no error. So I summarize the information below, hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the project and can't reproduce the issue. And the project runs well in my side.

**Test Result**

[image]

**My suggestion**

1. Please update your visual studio to latest version.
   My visual studio not the latest, but it works well.

   [image]
2. My .Net version

   [image]

Comment: the problem comes when you try to open Manufacturing Hub. How i do : at first i launch the server project, then i debug the client Manufacturing Hub project, separately

Comment: @Z.R.T. Let me check, pls wait

Comment: @Z.R.T. Which project should be the startup project ?  Manufacturing Hub ？

Comment: you will the message, unhandled error has occurred.  if you look in Chrome Browser,  you need to open Browser console, the exception is described there

Comment: you need to run server first, then open client . I do this in Visual Studio  via View / View in browser. View BlazeOrbital.CentralServer, then view BlazeOrbital.ManufacturingHub

Comment: @Z.R.T. I have seen the issue, let me investigate this issue, pls wait

Answer (score 0):

In order for Blazor Orbital to work, I took the following steps:

1. in VS2022 installer need to include
   .NET 6.0 WebAssembly Build Tools;
   .NET WebAssembly Build Tools
2. i removed `<NativeFileReference Include="..\rustqr\target\wasm32-unknown-emscripten\debug\librustqr.a" />` in BlazeOrbital.ManufacturingHub.csproj, because it threw an exception : "rustqr\target\wasm32-unknown-emscripten\debug\librustqr.a error"
3. also need to remember, first run (View/View In Browser) BlazeOrbital.CentralServer, then BlazeOrbital.ManufacturingHub

the Blazor Orbital run successfully without any error. no more issue with System.DllNotFoundException: e_sqlite3

PS: i use VS 2022 and the references in the BlazeOrbital-project remains the same, i only removed `<NativeFileReference Include="..\rustqr\target\wasm32-unknown-emscripten\debug\librustqr.a" />`